# How unsafe is it to cast an arbitrary function X=>Y to X => Unit in scala?

Tags: scala, type-erasure

More explicitly, can this code produce any errors in any scenrios:

```
def foreach[U](f :Int=>U) = f.asInstanceOf[Int=>Unit](1)
```

I know it works, and I have a vague idea why: any function, as an instance of a generic type, must define an erased version of `apply` and jvm performs type check only when the object is actually to be returned to a code where it had a concrete type (often miles away). So, in theory, as long as I never look at the returned value, I should be safe. I don't have an enough low-level understandings of java byte code, let alone `scalac`, to have any certainty about it.

Why would I want to do it? Look at the following example:

```
val b = new mutable.Buffer[Int]
val ints = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4)
ints foreach { b += _ }
```

It's a typical scala construct, as far as imperative style can be typical. `foreach` in this example takes an `Int` as an argument, and as scalac knows it to be an `Int`, it will create a closure with a specialized `apply(x :Int)`. Unfortunately, its return type in this case is a `mutable.Buffer[Int]`, which is an `AnyRef`. As far as I was able to see, `scalac` will never invoke a specialized `apply` providing an `AnyVal` argument if the result is an `AnyRef` (and vice versa). This means, that even if the caller applies the function to `Int`, underneath the function will box the argument and invoke the erased variant. Here of course it doesn't matter as they are boxed within the `List` anyway, but I'm talking about the principle.

For this reason I prefer to define this type of method as `foreach(f :X=>Unit)`, rather than `foreach[O](f: X=>O)` as it is in `TraversableOnce`. If the input sequence in the example had such a signature, everything would compile just as fine, and the compiler would ignore the actual type of the expression and generate a function with `Unit` return type, which - when applied to an unboxed `Int` - would invoke directly `void apply(Int x)`, without boxing.

The problem arises with interoperability - sometimes I need to call a method expecting a function with a `Unit` return type and all I have is a generic function returning Odin knows what. Of course, I could just write `f(_)` to box it in another function object instead of passing it directly, but it to large extent makes the whole optimisation of small tight loops moot.

Comment: What's wrong with this: `val f = (a: Int) => a.toString ; List(1, 2, 3, 4).foreach(f)` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are asking. Having generic parameter `O` rather than fixing it to `Unit` allows `Unit` returning functions as well as other functions to be passed. Thus it's less restrictive. Could you provide an example where the thing you are trying to achieve fails?

Comment: 1. What's wrong with Michael's example is that `f` will always box its argument, because it has AnyRef return type. By imposing a Unit return type, I enforce that any expression convertible to T=>Unit forSome T<:AnyVal will be invoked without boxing its argument.

Comment: I updated the question to be more explicit.

Comment: How about using `@specialized` annotation?: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/specialized.html. It's created exactly for that purpose.

Comment: @specialized is already defined for Function1 (and no feasible way outside of compiler plugin of extending its scope or mode of application). That's why it is possible to call a function without boxing at all. Unfortunately, if one wanted to defend onself from accidental boxing as in the example, one would have to specialize on return types, not only Unit; together with potential specialization of the element/argument type, it would generate about 100 copies of foreach method... Enforcing Unit return type, and casting the function when necessary reduces the product to linear number.